# Accessing Data in Constraint/Scroll/Grid

Tags: java, android

I want to create a new App. In this App I have a Constraint Layout with a Scroll View in it. In the Scroll View is also a GridLayout. My question is now how can I access the items in the GridLayout?

I tried it with:

```
    gridLayout = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.gridLayout);

    gridLayout.getColumnCount();

    int count = gridLayout.getChildCount();
    for(int i = 0 ; i <count ; i++)
    {
        TextView child = (TextView) gridLayout.getChildAt(i);
        System.out.println(child.getText());
    }
```

But this doesn´t work, so I tried to access only the Scroll View and the Constraint Layout but it fails too.

```
ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = (ConstraintLayout)findViewById(R.id.fragment_main);

    constraintLayout.getMaxHeight();
    ScrollView scroll = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
    scroll.getMaxScrollAmount();
```

The erros are all the same. Its the java.lang.NullPointerException. I don´t understand that is it not possible to get access from items in a ConstraintLayout or a ScrollView?

Comment: which line causes the NPE - the line that causes the NPE will have a `null` object. Maybe the findViewById ethods don't find a view??

Comment: The lines where I access on the variable with the view. So  gridLayout.getColumnCount();
constraintLayout.getMaxHeight(); and scroll.getMaxScrollAmount(); Yeah I think that they dont find a View but why is this so?

Comment: So gridlayout is null. `if (gridLayout == null) { System.err.println("damn, cannot find gridLayout!");} else { gridLayout.getColumnCount(); // ... }` .debug why you cannot get the gridlayout. What's the value of `R.id.gridLayout` ?

Comment: Sorry that im so late, but I tested it now. Here are the results: The if says cannot find GridLayout, and the Sysout with the ID says: 2131558540. I initialize the variable with gridLayout = (GridLayout) findViewByID(R.id.gridLayout); Why does it not work?

Comment: The weird thing is that I get the error from every variable and not only GridLayout. So I can´t access anything from what is in the constraintLayout. Anyone can help me?

Comment: Ok solved. Thanks to all I tried it in the wrong Method :)

Comment: If you solved it, can you describe what was wrong? Which  steps had to be done? Just in case anybody else encounters such a problem?